# Create nested json in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to create a nested json in Snowflake and have narrowed down the query like below where I have nested it on `id`. However, I want the nested json to also apply to the inner layer and I am finding it hard to get the right query for it.

```
WITH subquery AS (
  SELECT id, placeId, actionId, resultValue
  FROM my_table
)
SELECT id,
  '{"resultValues": {' || listagg('"' || placeId || '": {"' || actionId || '": ' || resultValue || '}', ',') within group (order by placeId) || '}}' as nested_json
FROM subquery
GROUP BY id;
```

Below is how the current result is looking like for each `id`.

[image]

I am trying to get the actionId1 and actionId2 grouped under the placeId1 and placeId2 so that it looks like below. How do I get this done? Any ideas would be appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Meet [FLATTEN()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html) and [LATERAL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/join-lateral.html) they like to hang out with [OBJECT_AGG()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_agg.html) who needs his own space via [CTE's](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-cte.html).

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
    parse_json(
        ' { "resultValues": [
 {  "placeId1": { "actionId1": 1.1   }   }, { "placeId1": { "actionId2": 1.2  } },
{ "placeId2": { "actionId1": 1.3  } }, { "placeId2":{ "actionId2": 1.4} } ] }'
    ) VOLIA
),
CTE2 AS (
SELECT
    DISTINCT KIAORA.PATH KIAORA,
    TE_REO.PATH TE_REO,
    OBJECT_AGG(MAORI.PATH, MAORI.VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY TE_REO.PATH) MAORI
FROM
    CTE,
    LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => VOLIA) KIAORA,
    LATERAL FLATTEN(KIAORA.VALUE) HELLO,
    LATERAL FLATTEN(HELLO.VALUE) TE_REO,
    LATERAL FLATTEN (INPUT => TE_REO.VALUE) MAORI
)
SELECT
DISTINCT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
    KIAORA,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(
        OBJECT_AGG(TE_REO, MAORI) OVER (PARTITION BY KIAORA)
    )
) ANSWER,
VOLIA
FROM
CTE2, CTE
```

after starting :
[image]